# NSDate Formatter Bug

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a Unix timestamp that I am attempting to convert with `NSDateFormatter()`, but when I try to pass my `NSDate` variable, I get an error: `Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'NSDate?'`

```
var releaseDate: NSDate?

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let seconds = Double(self.userA.releaseDate)

    let timestampDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: seconds)

    let stringTimeStamp = timestampDate.description

    print(stringTimeStamp) // 2016-07-29 04:49:54 +0000

    let releaseDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    releaseDateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
    releaseDate = releaseDateFormatter.stringFromDate(timestampDate)
}
```

I'm confused because didn't I explicity declare `timestampDate` as `NSDate`?

Comment: stringFromDate actually convert Date to String. You may need dateFromString, which will return a Date object from a String object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the `timestampDate`. The problem is that `releaseDate` is a `NSDate?` and you are trying to put the result of `stringFromDate` to it, which returns a `String`.

If you want to convert the timestamp to a user-readable string, you probably want to declare `releaseDate` as `String`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing `let stringTimeStamp = timestampDate.description` the **description** will return a **String** Object. So basically **stringTimeStamp** is a String type of object. So finally when your are doing `releaseDateFormatter.stringFromDate(timestampDate)` it is getting the error `Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type`.

Because **stringFromDate** actually converts a **NSDate** to **String**. It expects a **String** as the parameter. You may need **dateFromString**, which will convert a **String** to a **NSDate** object.